# How to create LinearLayout without margins

Tags: android, user-experience

Beginner here; I am trying to create an application where the design look like

[image]

Where I had a header(to wrap the logo), content, and footer.

The problem I faced that when I tried to achieve this sketch is that linear layout can't be fully wraped to the screen. Is there any hack or other way to achieve what I am trying to do.

I am getting something like:

[image]

Which makes it ugly to deal with the space, specially if I am trying to do a white background and different color in header.

**UPDATE**

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

**UPDATE2**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/black" />
```

Comment: Can you post your XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using any styles? If so, check what's in the style or just set your containers' `android:margin` and `android:padding` to `0`

**EDIT**

You need to use `match_parent` (equals to old, deprecated `fill_parent`) instead of `wrap_content` for your middle height otherwise your container won't stretch and you also may want to set `android:weight` to `1` for it.

Comment: Thanks! I have done that before, but it doesn't give results. check the xml

Comment: i tried it out, check the UPDATE2, but didn't give the desired results ? Is there any problem in my code. I need something similar to height:100% in css.

Comment: post you whole XML, not just snippet

Comment: Got it! Thanks, there was padding in RelativeLayout.

Comment: android:weight will eventually cause all nested views to be stretched and is to used with caution.

Comment: `with caution`? No, it's sufficient to just understand how it works.